# Angular and node js SPA- what happens behind the scenes when i navigate between components?

Tags: node.js, angular, single-page-application

im having trouble to understand how the combination of angular and node js can create a SPA website.

my question will be better understanable with an example:
lets say im trying to build a spa website:

client side - angular 4:

i have several components in my app, and configured routes to all these components.

i used `ng build` from the angular cli, and it created the dist folder with index.html.

on the server side - node js:
i used a static route for the index.html file.

when accessing the server via browser i get the index.html,
all the angular routes are working and can navigate between components successfully.

1. but i cant understand really what is happening behind the scenes every time i navigate to a diffrent component, 
   do i get that component from the server?
   (then it wont be SPA..)
2. when i access the static path the first time, does all the components get downloaded to the users browser, and from then on , the navigation only happens on the client?
3. what that index html contains ? what does the ng build command does ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad.  From the description: "Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. The router removes the view of the current route component from the DOM, and replaces it by the view of the newly routed component. It also pushes a new entry in the navigation history of the browser to do "as if" you really downloaded a new page from the URL of the new route.
2. Yes.
3. The content of the index.html is exactly what you see when viewing the source of the page in the browser. Or when viewing the content of the index.html file in the dist directory. It's simply an HTML page, with the root component, and a few JS scripts. These JS scripts are bundles, created by `ng build`, which contain the result of the TypeScript compilation of all your files, JS modules of Angular that your app uses and, deending on how you build the app (i.e. without or with --aot), the templates of the components or the result of the compilation of these templates (+ the CSS files of the component). In short, the whole app is bundled in those JS scripts.